# Unable to set up kubernetes because of "no matching manifest for unknown in the manifest list entries"

Tags: docker, kubernetes, arm

I am trying to set up kubernetes by following this guide on pine64:
https://itnext.io/create-a-kubernetes-cluster-with-pine64-428fc62d72e7

I got everything set up so far, but when I try to run

```
sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16
```

I get the following error(and a few more like this):

`[ERROR ImagePull]: failed to pull image k8s.gcr.io/kube-apiserver:v1.13.1: output: v1.13.1: Pulling from kube-apiserver
no matching manifest for unknown in the manifest list entries`

I am assuming this has to do with the architecture, but I am not sure.
This is what uname -a returns:
`Linux k8s-master-1 3.10.104-2-pine64-longsleep #113 SMP PREEMPT Thu Dec 15 21:46:07 CET 2016 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux`

`sudo docker pull k8s.gcr.io/kube-apiserver:v1.13.1` also returns the same error:

`v1.13.1: Pulling from kube-apiserver
no matching manifest for unknown in the manifest list entries`

I have also tried `sudo docker pull k8s.gcr.io/kube-apiserver-arm64:v1.13.1`
and that will pull the image, but it does not make the first error message go away

Comment: Have you tried to pull images via `kubeadm` itself: `sudo kubeadm config images pull`?

Comment: I have but that makes no difference

Comment: What is your Docker version?